# How can I cheaply replace basement ceiling tiles?

Tags: basement, ceiling

I live in Edmonton, Alberta and must replace the old ceiling tiles. I have been told it could cost more money than I have to replace it. Is there a low cost way to do this?

I am having the electrical upgraded so the ceiling will be messed-up. People are living in there and so something must be done to repair the ceiling!!

Does anyone have an answer for me?

Comment: What's going on with the old tiles? Why must you replace them? If this needs to be done simply because of electrical upgrades, is it possible to carefully remove the tiles first and then attempt to put them back carefully?

Comment: Picture? Suspended ceiling tile? If the track is in good condition paint it and buy packages of tiles.